# I would like to retrieve data from a Firestore collection and store the data in a list

Tags: flutter

I am trying to retrieve data that I stored in my Firestore collection. Each document stored has fields that look like this:

```dart
  events.doc(eventID).set({
    'eventID': eventID,
    'eventName': eventName,
    'location': location,
    'duration': duration,
    'category': category,
    'description': description,
    'creator': creatorUID,
    'guests': null,
  });
```

Once retrieved, I wanted to store each unique document's data in a List and loop through the list to access the individual document's data and display it.
How would I go about this?

Edit:
This is what I've tried so far:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

CollectionReference events = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Events");
DocumentReference eventDocs = events.doc();
List<Event> firebaseEvents = <Event>[];

class Event {
  final String eventName, eventID, location, duration, description, creatorID, imagePath;
  String category;
  final List categoryID, galleryImages;
  List<dynamic> userEvents;

  Event(
      {
        this.imagePath,
        this.eventName,
        this.eventID,
        this.location,
        this.duration,
        this.description,
        this.creatorID,
        this.categoryID,
        this.galleryImages,
      }
      );

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final eventsList = [];

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> eventDocs = events.snapshots();

    eventDocs.forEach((element) {
      element.docs.asMap().forEach((key, value) {

        final firebaseEventDocs = Event(
            imagePath: "assets/event_images/5_km_downtown_run.jpeg",
            eventName: element.docs[key]["eventName"],
            description: element.docs[key]["description"],
            location: element.docs[key]["location"],
            duration: element.docs[key]["duration"],
            galleryImages: [],
            categoryID: [0,element.docs[key]["category"]]);

        eventsList.add({
          firebaseEventDocs,
        });
      });
    });
    userEvents = eventsList;
  }
}
```

I am also trying to get elements (they are events) where the category ID assigned is specific like so:

```dart
    for (final event in Event.where((e) => e
           .categoryIds
           .contains(appState.selectedCategoryId)))
```

but I get an error on the where saying "The method 'where' isn't defined for the type 'Event'".

Comment: Please add the code  that you have already tried to obtain the above functionality. for more see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've added the code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing Event the class instead of the list userEvents that I created.